# Rails: With Bootstrap-Sass, How Do You Use Mixins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gradient

I could not find good references about how to use mixins from bootstrap-sass. I'm trying to add gradient effect to my background color, and I want to learn how to use the built-in gradient function from the mixin.

```
// Gradients
@mixin gradient-horizontal($startColor: #555, $endColor: #333) {
  background-color: $endColor;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, $startColor, $endColor); // FF 3.6+
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from($startColor),     to($endColor)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, $startColor, $endColor); // Safari   5.1+, Chrome 10+
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, $startColor, $endColor); // Opera 11.10
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, $startColor, $endColor); // Standard, IE10
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#{ie-hex-  str($startColor)}', endColorstr='#{ie-hex-str($endColor)}', GradientType=1); // IE9 and   down
}
```

In **application.css.scss** file, I tried

```
body {
padding-right: 50px;
padding-left: 50px;
gradient-vertical($startcolor: $white, $endcolor: #08C);
}
```

But did not work. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  @include gradient-vertical($white, #08c);
}
```

The mixin arguments are usually optional (unless you omit some or declare them out of order), but there's nothing wrong with using them like you have  (`$startcolor: $white`, etc). The only thing you are missing is the `@include`. Also make sure you have `@import "bootstrap";` at the top of `application.css.scss`.

You can refer to [SASS Reference](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) for more info.